# I want recursive constructor invocation - how do I get around the error?

Tags: java, recursion, constructor, invocation

I'm coding a fun assignment for a class I'm taking and its all about polymorphism and coding objects, etc...  Basically, we are asked to code a "critter" object that fights other students critters.

How can I make it that so when a certain method is called on my critter object, (lose(), when my critter loses the fight) that it then calls its own constructor again so it is "reborn"?

Here's my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Husky extends Critter {
   //fields
   private int x = getWidth();
   private int y = getHeight();
   private Random r = new Random();
   private Direction[] directions = {Direction.NORTH, Direction.SOUTH, Direction.EAST, Direction.WEST};

   public Husky() {}

   public boolean eat() {
      return true;
   }

   public Attack fight(String opponent) {
      if (opponent.equals("%")) {
         return Attack.ROAR;
      } else if (opponent.equals("^") || opponent.equals(">") || opponent.equals("V")
     || opponent.equals("<") || opponent.equals("0")) {

     return Attack.SCRATCH;
      } else {
         return Attack.ROAR;
      } 
   }


   public Direction getMove() {
      int z = r.nextInt(4);
      return directions[z];
   }  

   public Color getColor() {
      return Color.CYAN;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return "∏";
   }

   public void lose() {
      this();
   }
}
```

I want my critter to be undying, basically.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can have lose create a new Husky

```
public void lose() { new Husky(); }
```

or return one :

```
public Critter lose() {  return new Husky();  }
```